# PyQT Qtabwidget hide and close certain tab

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt

Is it possible to hide and close a certain tab in Qtabwidget? I have 5 tabs, two of them are plots and generated while using my software. First I want to hide the two plots in the beginning and second I want to make them closable after there were generated. Is this possible? With `self.setTabsClosable(True)` all tabs will be closable.

Thanks

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomTabWidget (QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)
        for i in range(1, 10):
            self.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), 'Tab %d' % i)

    def closeTab (self, currentIndex):
        currentQWidget = self.widget(currentIndex)
        currentQWidget.deleteLater()
        self.removeTab(currentIndex)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomTabWidget = QCustomTabWidget()
myQCustomTabWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the close button of the tabs that should not be closed. This is done by with the function `setTabButton` of `QTabBar`, like this:

```
QtGui.QTabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(0, QtGui.QTabBar.RightSide,None)
```

Here, we set the button of the first tab to be `None`.

With the same function, you could also create your own close button on a tab (and remove `self.setTabsClosable(True)`)