# How can I remove the Close Button from the "main" tab but not other tabs using PyQt5?

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt5

I am creating an application which has a main homepage tab with a table displaying data and  then when a user selects one of the rows a new tab opens with more details. To make the tabs able to be closed I have set `self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)`. But I would like to make the first tab unable to be closed (as otherwise you can close all the tabs and nothing else remains on the application.) See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udKwK.png)

I tried this line of code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840701/pyqt-qtabwidget-hide-and-close-certain-tab) : `self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(0, QtGui.QTabBar.RightSide, None)`. But it doesn't seem to work (I think as I am not using a tabBar, im using QTabWidget), I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have displayed my code below. Apologies in advance, this is my first ever post and im not sure if I am doing this correctly.

```
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1081, 741))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(0, QTabBar.RightSide, None)
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
```

Comment: You need to add `self.tab` to `self.tabWidget` before setting the tab button to None.

Comment: @Heike Thank you so much!!! I've been stuck for hours trying to sort this I can't believe all I had to do was move it down below adding the tab.